# Does island hopping increase enemy stacks in Armored Princess

Tags: kings-bounty-armored-princess

I would like to know if hopping from island to island causes some enemy stacks getting bigger. I'm playing on the hardest difficulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't. In fact, island hopping is necessary to win the game, even in easier difficulty levels.